# VBA: My SolverAdd is not adding my constraints

Tags: excel, vba

It adds my objective and my variable range. It does not add the constraints. I can't figure it out.

```
 SolverReset
        SolverOK setCell:=Range("Objective1"), _
            maxMinVal:=1, _
            byChange:=Range("VarChange1")
        SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("ExpenseSum1"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="allocationAmount"
        SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("VarChange1"), Relation:=1, FormulaText:="allocationDivided"
        SolverAdd cellRef:=Range("VarChange1"), Relation:=3, FormulaText:="Difference6"
        
        
        
        
        SolverSolve userFinish:=False
```